# MySQL Scheduled Event and server offline?

Tags: mysql

I have an event planned to run a 00:00. But the server won't be online at that point, seeing it's a local development server. Will it run the next time the server is online, or will it just be forgotten?

The event is as follows:

```
    CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` 
    EVENT `winners` 
    ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY STARTS '2013-02-19 00:00:00' 
    ON COMPLETION PRESERVE ENABLE
    DO 
    UPDATE `data`
    SET wins = wins + 1
    ORDER BY cur_score DESC 
    LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Are you asking whether the "missed" event will be "made up" when the server restarts, if the server isn't online when the event should have fired?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should run just fine.

However, it is just like configuring Windows Updates. If you configure Windows Updates for 12:00 AM, shutting down the Windows Machine at 11:59 PM and starting it back at 12:01 AM prevents Windows from checking for Updates.

When such a shutdown is occasional, leaving everything alone will cause the DB server to bring up the MySQL Event at midnight so long as mysqld is running at midnight.